# A kind of memory leak on nodeJs?

Tags: node.js, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have some problems with a "memory leak issue" in several versions of NodeJs.

**EDIT :**
I've tried several version of nodeJs : v0.8.10, v0.10.22, v0.10.23, v0.10.24 ...
I'm under MacOsX 10.9.1.

Here is my *test.js* :

```
function a() { 
  console.log( process.memoryUsage() );
  global.gc();
}
var b = setInterval(a,5000);
```

I launch it with :

```
node --expose-gc test.js
```

Here is the output :

```
 { rss: 12312576, heapTotal: 5115392, heapUsed: 2429656 }
 { rss: 13406208, heapTotal: 6163968, heapUsed: 2139848 }
 { rss: 13463552, heapTotal: 6163968, heapUsed: 1911320 }
 { rss: 14295040, heapTotal: 6163968, heapUsed: 1919632 }
 { rss: 14434304, heapTotal: 6163968, heapUsed: 1898944 }
 ... etc ...
```

As you can notice, RSS doesn't stop growing, heapTotal is stable, heapUsed moves but stays balanced.

**Does somebody understand why RSS (Resident Set Size) is still growing ?** Is it normal ? Is it a native node memory leak ?

What's happen on your machines ?

**EDIT :**
I've tried on a linux server and the headTotal and RSS are stable ! Looks like a issue on nodeJs for MacOs ?! Somebody knows why ?

Thanks !

Comment: What version of Node are you on? Running `v0.10.23` on Linux shows a constant value for `rss` and `heapTotal`.

Comment: Node v0.10.20 on Linux. The value of rss doesn't move at all. You should probably mention the version of node you are running. (Tip: You can use `node -v` to find out the version)

Comment: Yes, sorry, i've tried several version of NodeJs : v0.8.10, v0.10.22, v0.10.23, v0.10.24 ... Your RSS is constant with that code ?! In 2 hours, mine goes from 22Mo to 80Mo...

Comment: Sounds like a bug in node. Should report it if you haven't.